# Solution of differential Equation using frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

How to calculate the two linearly independent solutions of the differential equation

x(x − 1)y'' + (3x−1)y'+ y = 0?

My approach was by using the Frobenius method as x=0 and x=1 are regular singular points and then finding the roots of the indicial equation and then by seeing the difference of the roots I got the solution to be 1/(1-x), and by using the method of reduction the second one turns out to be log_e(x)/(1-x), but the second solution does not seem to satisfy the equation when I put it back in the DE. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Both solutions work, you must have an algebra error.

Comment: Thanks for the help, ya I figured it out.